# Offset в шейдере для SpriteRenderer

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

Пытаюсь написать шейдер со сдвигом для `SpriteRenderer`. Текстура двигается нормально, но альфа канал почему - то остается на месте, как это можно исправить? Сдвиг делаю следующим образом:

```
v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
    {
        v2f OUT;
        IN.texcoord.x += OffsetX;

        OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
        OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord * half2(RepeatX, RepeatY);
        OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
#ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
        OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap(OUT.vertex);
#endif

        return OUT;
    }
```